# Coerce to number

Tags: javascript

I have often seen the trick

```
after = +after;
```

to coerce the variable `after` to a number. Reading through the [Node.JS source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/timers.js#L188) I found another method:

```
after *= 1; // coalesce to number or NaN
```

Are the two methods strictly equivalent in their behaviour?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes. Both [Unary Operator `+`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.6) and [Multiplicative Operators](http://es5.github.io/#x11.5) such as `*` (called from [Compound Assignment](http://es5.github.io/#x11.13.2) `op=`) invoke the internal [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) algorithm.

You can even use a 3rd option by statically calling the [`Number` constructor](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.1.1):

```
after = Number(after);
```

Comment: The third option is by far the slowest, however: http://jsperf.com/testing-number-coercion

Comment: The third option is the most self-documenting though.

Answer (score 5):

After a quick [google to make sure my suspicions were true](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/), I came to this conclusion. Using the `+` operator to convert to a number is faster, because no mathematical operations occur after type-casting, whereas using the `*=` approach means that after `after` is converted, it will be multiplied by `1`.

Comment: So there are no behavioural differences, just speed and syntax?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but the question related to the syntax given, which I think I've answered. If the casting is any different based on the operator, I don't know. That would require a geek with powers far beyond mine!

Answer (score 1):

Note: In some instances `after = after-0` invokes different behaviour than `after = after+0`. I've noticed it with dates.

This is tested in Chrome v39 only:

```
var date = new Date(2000,0,1);
date += date; //"Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"
var date2 = new Date(2000,0,1);
date2 + 0; //"Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)0"
date2 - 0; //946684800000
date2 * 1; //946684800000
```

I don't know what is defined in the JS spec, but with dates, because both the date and the number can be cast to a string, and the + operator works on a string, then Chrome goes with a string concatenation. Because the - operator has no string equivalent, it falls back to number comparison.

I've found this useful when coercing dates into numbers for comparisons

Comment: It is related to the [`Symbol.toPrimitive` symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/@@toPrimitive).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however note that it is only the *unary* + operator that does this. I.e. `10 + "10"` will give you `"1010"`.

A perhaps less error prone option is to use what asm.js does:

```
10 + ("10"|0)
```

Although on the down-side it does require the brackets. It should be the fastest option in any case (probably equal to unary +).

Comment: This will convert the number to an integer, not just a number (ie: `("10.7"|0) === 10`).  If you just want to convert the string to a number, use unary plus (`+"10.7" === 10.7`)